# Mongo collection in Meteor is inserting junk

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongo-collection

I'm trying to create a Mongo collection that can be inserted into from client side. When I call Courses.insert it succeeds, but is putting junk fields into my collection.

Code:

/imports/api/createCourse.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import './createCourse.html'
import { Courses } from './collections.js'

if (Meteor.isClient) {
Template.createCourse.events({
    'submit #register_form' : function(event) {
        var cName = event.target.courseName.value;
        var aCode = event.target.accessCode.value;
        var aClosedDate = event.target.accessClosedDate.value;
        console.log("Course Form Submitted.");

        //var cID = new ObjectID;
        var toInsert = {
            courseID: 1,
            ownerID: Meteor.userId(),
            courseName: cName,
            restrictionMask: 0, //????
            accessCode: aCode,
            accessClosedDate: aClosedDate,
            disabled: false
        };

          //   Courses.schema.validate(toInsert);
            console.log("about to insert");
            var result = Courses.insert(Meteor.userId(), toInsert);
            console.log(result);

    }
})
```

}

/imports/api/collections.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import 'meteor/aldeed:collection2';

export const Courses = new Mongo.Collection("courses");

Courses.allow({
    'insert': function (userId) {
        return true;
    }
})
```

Once I call `Courses.insert(Meteor.userId(), toInsert);` I open up a console and view the contents of the collection with `db.courses.find()`

The meteor console output is:

```
{ "_id" : "NvcBX7MnSMx2LyJFz", "0" : "m", "1" : "X", "2" : "3", "3" : "H", "4" : "m", "5" : "i", "6" : "C", "7" : "p
", "8" : "p", "9" : "f", "10" : "a", "11" : "H", "12" : "e", "13" : "v", "14" : "9", "15" : "7", "16" : "R" }
```

**Note: Everytime I insert into the database, the _id is different, but the other key:values are all identical no matter what data I attempt to insert.**

The javascript console output is:

```
Course Form Submitted.
createCourse.js:33 about to insert
createCourse.js:35 NvcBX7MnSMx2LyJFz
```

Can someone please help to point out what the issue is. I would also appreciate any feedback on secure practices regarding collections and any feedback in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to pass the userId explicitly to insert. The insert function is documented in [Meteor API](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-insert). The junk that you see is the userId.

Just use:

```
var result = Courses.insert(toInsert);
```

Comment: Thank you, The reason I was using the userId() is because of the 'insert' : function (userId). It was originally 'insert' : function(userId, doc). However, I don't understand exactly what this function does? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Meteor.userId() from the insert query. Just insert like this:

```
var result = Courses.insert(toInsert);
```